# React Native Button onPress function and props concern

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have React Native project. I am new to React. I was told not to put functions in the jsx as it's bad practice. Looking for guidance to keep component clean

```
// App.js
export const App = () => {
  // other things
  return (
          <CustomButton onButtonPress={()=> someFunction} />
  )
}
```

Then my custom component that I am in question. Should I create a functions which will included the prop or do I use the prop directly in the jsx

```
export const CustomButton = (props) => {
  <Button
    onPress={() => props.onButtonPress(item.socketId)}>
    Decline
   </Button>
```

or

```
export const CustomButton = (props) => {
  const handleDisconnect = (socketId) => {
    props.onButtonPress(socketId)
  }

  <Button
    onPress={() => handleDisconnect(item.socketId)}>
    Decline
   </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short. React use function component, if you not use memo, your function will be create again and take some memory and time. Also arrow function will recreate too.

```
import React, { memo, useCallback } from "react";
import { Text, Button } from "react-native";

const ClearCustomButtom = memo(({ onPress, title }) => (
  <Button onPress={onPress}>
    <Text>{title}</Text>
  </Button>
));

const ExtraCustomButtom = memo(({ onPress, title, socketId }) => {
  const handlePress = () => {
    console.log("Some extra action");
    onPress(socketId);
  };

  return (
    <Button onPress={handlePress}>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </Button>
  );
});

const RequestCustomButtom = memo(({ url, title }) => {
  const handlePress = () => {
    //send request on server
  };

  return (
    <Button onPress={handlePress}>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </Button>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  //UseCallback create point for put in button props, not function but point. Without useCallback component will rerender every time.
  const handlePressClearDecline = useCallback(() => {}, []);

  const handlePressExtraDecline = useCallback((socketId) => {
    console.log(socketId);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ClearCustomButtom
        title="ClearCustomButton"
        onPress={handlePressClearDecline}
      />
      <ExtraCustomButtom
        title="ExtraCustomButton"
        onPress={handlePressExtraDecline}
        socketId="777"
      />
      <RequestCustomButtom title="Send request" />
    </>
  );
}
```

This example of most common case in react-native, how to write pressable component.